# Are templates within the scope of this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are templates within the scope of this site? How I see it, they shouldn't be. It's basically someone else's scene, and they should be responsible for making sure that it works properly.

If someone is having issues with that template, wouldn't that be the creators responsibility to fix it? While it's not a separate piece of software, or an unofficial addon, it's similar to one because someone unofficially created it. Unless they released it with their own license, there is no guarantee that it works, and it could have lots of issues.

Now, if it's something regarding extending a template, or the author can prove that it's not an issue with the template, then I think it should be within the scope. But I think that questions [like this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35342/video-files-dont-load-audio-is-missing?noredirect=1#comment58054_35342), should be out of the scope, because it could easily be an issue with the template, and nothing that the user needs or wants to learn about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why should we particularly care if the OP is using a template or not?

If the [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/35342/599) "didn't open with blender, also the audio doesn't work" had been asked without mentioning "template", would it be considered off topic? Perhaps the way it was written it might be considered "unclear", but I don't think it would be considered *off-topic*.

The afformentioned question appears to be about issues encountered while using blender with external assets (video, audio). IMO this fits under our [scope](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> The Blender Stack Exchange site is for people who use Blender to create 3D graphics, animations, or games.

Now if the question was "what's the best way to use this template", then yes, that has more to do with the intent of the template author than with blender (and I would consider that off-topic).